# How to add Data to a WPF datagrid programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How can I add data Items  to a `DataGrid` programmatically in WPF which do not have bindings? The `DataGrid` has 4 columns.

Comment: DataBinding and adding items programmatically are not mutally exclusive.

Comment: `DataGrid.Items.Add(new DataItem());` I tried this but no idea to create `DataItem()`

Comment: Then how to bind the `columns` that are not from a `dataset`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is not very clear, what You like to do. I guess, You have defined some place where You want to put the DataGrid. For illustration purposes, I created a new WPF project and use the code provided by chridram, who posted the first answer.

In the following MainWindow.xaml I name the Grid MainGrid to access it in the code behind:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfExperiments.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Name="MainGrid"/>
</Window>
```

The DataItem class is not a WPF class, but a custom class created by Yourself:

```cs
public class DataItem
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
    public string Column4 { get; set; }
}
```

To let the DataGrid display data stored in DataItem objects programmatically, You may do the following:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Your programmatically created DataGrid is attached to MainGrid here
        var dg = new DataGrid();
        this.MainGrid.Children.Add(dg);

        // create four columns here with same names as the DataItem's properties
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i)
        {
            var column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            column.Header = "Column" + i;
            column.Binding = new Binding("Column" + i);
            dg.Columns.Add(column);
        }

        // create and add two lines of fake data to be displayed, here
        dg.Items.Add(new DataItem { Column1 = "a.1", Column2 = "a.2", Column3 = "a.3", Column4 = "a.4" });
        dg.Items.Add(new DataItem { Column1 = "b.1", Column2 = "b.2", Column3 = "b.3", Column4 = "b.4" });
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Greetings
Jörg

Comment: This is working well.But i want to do this for a `DataGrid` that is already created in `XAML`.I tried this on it,i can see columns getting added but nothing displays in the columns.I think the problem is with `DataBinding`.
i tried
`<DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Width="80" x:Name="colCode" Binding="{Binding}">`  
and   `<DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Width="80" x:Name="colCode" Binding="{Binding ElementName=colCode}">`

Comment: Its alrite.I got it done.Problem was different column names and `DataItem` names.

Answer (score 2):

this a function which i use for retrive data from database
    
`string query = "Select * from VWpatientinfo";
    DataTable dataTableObject = new DataTable("Table Name");`

```
obj.DataRetrive(query,dataTableObject);
DataGridName.ItemsSource = dataTableObject.DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

.xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="10">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Column1}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Column2}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

.cs:

```
public class DataItem
{
    public bool Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataItem item = new DataItem();
        item.Column1 = true;
        item.Column2 = "test";
        dataGrid.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```